# How to switch between different HTML elements with the same onclick function?

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

Right now i have four images which are being dynamically presented on html. This is done via an onload function. Basically when i click on of those wheels I would like the image to change for around one second then go back. But right now only one wheel changes colour which is quite annoying.

```
function setWheels() {
            document.querySelector(".blue-wheel").innerHTML = "<img src='blue-dark.svg.svg' onclick='buttonEvent()'>";
            document.querySelector(".red-wheel").innerHTML = "<img src='red-dark.svg.svg' onclick='buttonEvent()'>";
            document.querySelector(".green-wheel").innerHTML = "<img src='green-dark.svg.svg'>";
            document.querySelector(".yellow-wheel").innerHTML = "<img src='yellow-dark.svg.svg'>";
        
        }


        function buttonEvent() {
            if (document.querySelector(".blue-wheel")) {
                document.querySelector(".blue-wheel").innerHTML = "<img src='blue-light.svg.svg'>";
                setTimeout(setWheels, 800);
            }
            else if (document.querySelector(".red-wheel")) {
                document.querySelector(".red-wheel").innerHTML =<img src='red-light.svg.svg'>";
                setTimeout(setWheels, 800);
            }

        }
```

I havnt added the other coloured wheels as i do predict that they will have the same effect. I do believe that the setTimeout may be one of the problems as I'm calling the setWheels function but the first if statement seems to be the only one that changes colour even when i click the other div.

Comment: Your if/else doesn't make sense . The else won't occur since the first part of `if()` is always true. That is why you only see one change

Comment: Do some research into how to isolate the specific  element that a user event occurs on

Comment: could i use the .clicked method in the if statements

Answer (score 1):

Your if statements aren't checking anything useful. `if(document.querySelector(".blue-wheel"))` is only checking if that element is there, not if the image inside was clicked.

If you want to know which image was clicked, pass it in as a parameter to the function.

```html
<img src='blue-dark.svg.svg' onclick='buttonEvent(this)'>
```

and in your javascript, just change the src for the image that was clicked and then set a timeout to change it back.

```js
function buttonEvent(e) {
    e.src = e.src.replace('dark', 'light');
    setTimeout(() => {e.src = e.src.replace('light', 'dark')}, 800);
}
```

if you want to protect against fast clicking while the image is already highlighted (improve performance) you can add a return:

```js
function buttonEvent(e) {
    if (!e.src.includes('dark')) return;
    e.src = e.src.replace('dark', 'light');
    setTimeout(() => {e.src = e.src.replace('light', 'dark')}, 800);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a "

```
.innerHTML =<img src='red-light.svg.svg'>";
```

should be

```
.innerHTML = "<img src='red-light.svg.svg'>";
```

Comment: Please add some more details to your answer such that others can learn from it. Does adding this quote help to switch between the different elements properly?

Answer (score -1):

you can use a variable (let x=0) to count on what image are you on. then make function that will see what x = 0 so it will show the first image then add one to the x (like "x++")but before you show the image you need to remove the last one, so then you need to loop through the images (you can give the same class to the images) like ".forEach()" and in that function you can see if that image is on the page or is shown to the user then just remove it, then x =1 in that case just show the second image and so on. you can add "if" statement that will check "if x>=(image count)" when that happens then just "x=0" and it will reset

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).